# how to use map and boolean variables inside paths? (can't return the attributes using routers)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I use `map` and `boolean variables` inside those two `paths` and still return the attributes?
Those are the `routes`:

```
<Route exact path='/' component={()=>{return <Addroom/>}}/>
<Route exact path='/room' component={()=>{return <Room/>}}/>
```

Those are the the `components` that I want to return inside the `routes`:

```
  {this.state.roomsList.map((element, key) => {
          return (
            <Room
              id={key + 1}
              key={key}
              r={element.room}
              rt={element.roomType}
              ct={element.colorType}
              sr={element.boxColor}
            />
          );
        })}

        {this.state.isActive ? (
          <Addroom add={this.create} />
        ) : (
          <button style={{backgroundColor: "aquamarine", height: "20px", width: "60px", borderRadius: "5px", border: "2px"}} onClick={this.handleShow}>Create</button>
        )}
```

Thank you! (:

Comment: Can you clarify how the second snippet relates to the first? It isn't clear what you want to do with the second snippet.

Comment: I want to return Room component and Addroom component (the second snippet) but inside those paths (first snippet).

Comment: I want to run the app in the same way but when the routers are defined in the project the algorithms stop working because I put them in incorrectly. In the end I would like to connect these two components correctly. it seems that the syntax or the locations wrong, I tried to understand how should I write it right in this project but there are too many details in my code already.

Comment: Are you basically trying to pass `this.state.isActive` to the `Active` component in the "/" path, and you want to map `this.state.roomsList` to individual `Route`s? Is this correct?

Comment: No, not to individual Routes, I want to show `Addroom` in the same way before I used routers but when I'm using the components in the routes as it is now (including all the code that already exists and defined to return the components) with the routers are defined in the project the algorithms stop working because I put them in incorrectly.

Comment: I've been trying to deal with this for some time now, here are questions in a wording that a little difficult understand on the exact same subject that I asked:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63059386/connecting-two-components-one-with-defined-routers-and-one-not
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63056498/terminal-failed-to-compile-using-react-routers-wrong-syntax-probably
 thank you for trying helping me!

Comment: Ah, so is it that all that code all lives in the same component, and for path "/" you want to render `Addroom` with the `add` prop **only when** `state.isActive` is true, and for path "/room" you want to render `this.state.roomsList`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218572/discussion-between-hardbeard-and-drew-reese).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to render the above second code snippet into one of two routes. You can merge the two implementations

1. Define anonymous inner functional components to pass to the `Route`.
2. Use the `Route`'s [`render`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/render-func) to render the anonymous inner functional component. This avoids remounting the component on every render cycle.
3. When using a `Switch` only the first route match is returned and rendered, and *less* specific paths will match before more specific paths, so switch the order to define the more specific paths *before* less specific paths. This removes the need to add the `exact` prop to *every* route.

Code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import './App.css';
import Addroom from "./components/Addroom.js";
import Room from "./components/Room.js";

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    roomsList: [],
    isActive: false
  };

  handleShow = () => {
    this.setState({ isActive: true });
  };

  handleHide = () => {
    this.setState({ isActive: false });
  };

  create = r => {
    this.setState({
      roomsList: [...this.state.roomsList, r],
      isActive: false
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { isActive, roomsList } = this.state;

    return (
      <div
        className="backGroundMain"
        style={{
          backgroundColor: "lightseagreen",
          height: "600px",
          width: "850px"
        }}
      >
        <h1
          style={{
            backgroundColor: "aquamarine",
            height: "40px",
            width: "270px",
            borderRadius: "5px",
            border: "2px",
            margin: "15px"
          }}
        >
          My Smart House
        </h1>

        <Router>
          <Switch>
            <Route
              path='/room'
              render={()=> {
                return roomsList.map((element, key) => (
                  <Room
                    id={key + 1}
                    key={key}
                    r={element.room}
                    rt={element.roomType}
                    ct={element.colorType}
                    sr={element.boxColor}
                  />
                ))
              }}
            />
            <Route
              path='/'
              render={routeProps => isActive ? (
                  <Addroom add={this.create} {...routeProps}/>
                ) : (
                  <button
                    style={{
                      backgroundColor: "aquamarine",
                      height: "20px",
                      width: "60px",
                      borderRadius: "5px",
                      border: "2px"
                    }}
                    onClick={this.handleShow}
                  >
                    Create
                  </button>
                )
              }
            />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: So you have defined the `functional component` in the `route` as anonymous so that it can be used and presented as we wish.
You prevented the render at first and now you allow to render just in case isActive is `true`, Then it renders the same `component`, yes? that way? I think I understand..

Comment: I tried to run a debugger to deepen and understand what you did a little more, to know if I can use it, But it seems I will need another solution so I can continue to build on the project and not get involved.. I will probably continue in a different way but thank you very much, very useful,  I learned new effective way to use bypass the render and pull specific `props`.

Comment: I just really wanted to keep the way I displayed the components
I have now created a new component where the ready-made rooms that will displayed in a route which the user could get there with clicking on link that defined with a path and it doesn't work! the Terminal not identified my functions as defined..
I can send you the code snippet in the chat if you'd like (:
Thank you again!

Comment: @HardBeard I don't have a lot of context, and I don't know what your `roomsList` array contains, but a defined path like "/room" to me implies a single room. Perhaps it'd make sense to define path as "/room/:roomId" and use your links to specify the full path, i.e. "/room/123", and use the route props to extract the `roomId` match param to render the correct room data from the array. Good luck though with whatever direction you decide to go on this.